# Global variable per user in Web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, static, global-variables

I have a stateless SOAP Web service(Java, Spring, Tomcat).

I want to keep some global variables per session for easy access and avoiding using static variables cause they will have a container scope.

How can I do that? if only way to do it is with spring bean scopes then which scope is better prototype or singleton scope and why?

thanks

Comment: *global* variables *per session* in a *stateless* service? Confused...

Comment: lets say you want to keep clients IP address during the session and make it easily accessible from every class like a static variable, but I cant use static cause every client will have different IP's

Comment: @jan - that makes the session stateful (the users IP address is the sessions state)

Comment: But webservice will forget everything about the user once session is over. I mean after every response, session is over, thats what I meant by stateless

Comment: @jan - I understand - so you need a suggestion on how to *persist data between sessions*. Like the stateless bean can read from a write to a database.

Comment: @Andreas No, persist and easy access data only during the time between clients request and servers response. Not sure if this is a session or request scope.

Comment: @Jan - so the web service is *asynchronous*: after receiving a request the session (1) either stores a callback URL to deliver the response (push) or (2) responds with an ID which the client can use to periodically look for results (pull). So to my understanding, an asynchronous web service requires a stateful session (to store callback URL or ID *in* the session)

Comment: Well, I dont think these are related to my problem. But I liked your point and would like to learn more; If a web service does not store any url or id(stateless web service in your definition?) how will it respond in anyway to client? what I know ny definition by stateless web service is once the web service responds to client then it forgets about everything about client.

Comment: Also I checked and I can say my web service is Synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring bean scope could be used for this .

session scope

example:

```
<bean id="customerService" class="com.customer.services.CustomerService" 
     scope="session"/>
```

Comment: *Request* scope is more appropriate for a web service, since you might not be using cookies.

Comment: @artbristol Thanks, Could you tell me why it is more appropriate? and which one is easy to implement?

Comment: I found this and have no idea how to use a context like this: "Note that in order to use session scope, you have to be using a web-aware Spring application context, such as XmlWebApplicationContext. Otherwise there's no way for the scoped proxy to reference a current session"

Comment: Request and session scope are the same difficulty to implement - just choose the scope in the bean config per this answer. Request scope means the bean will fall out of scope at the end of each particular HTTP request instead of persisting across multiple requests within the same HTTP session.

Answer (score 2):

(This is not an answer to the original question but tries to answer some additional questions from the comment area)

A *Session bean* may be *stateless* or *stateful*. If it is *stateless*, it takes a request, sends a response (maybe) and is destroyed afterwards. A *stateful* session stores some parameters (a *state*) that can be reused for other method calls - like a bean that simply counts internally how often it has been invoked.

A *synchronous web service* can be implemented with a *stateless session bean*. It takes a request, does some calculation, returns a response and is finished (the bean can be destroyed). In that case the client waits for the answer, it's like calling a simple Java method.

That's different for *asynchronous web services*: The service receives a request and either

- receives a callback URL *or*
- responds with a session ID

In any case - the client won't wait for the response but continue, until it receives the response, either because

- the *service* has sent the response to the clients callback method *or*
- the client has polled several times using the session ID and eventually polled the service response.

Asynchronous service is like starting a Java thread: you start it, continue with your work and at some point you get the result (or a notification, that the result is ready)

And an asynchronous service *needs* some kind of persistence store to store the session ID or the callback URL *while* the service session is active. The *service session* is stateful, the *session beans* that are needed for the service can be *stateless*.